# Aerospike EOFException repeatedly

Tags: java, asynchronous, aerospike

Using aerospike Java client 4.0.6

aerospike server 3.14.1.2

Repeatedly getting following exception :

```
com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: java.io.EOFException
    at com.aerospike.client.async.NioEventLoop.processKey(NioEventLoop.java:276)
    at com.aerospike.client.async.NioEventLoop.runCommands(NioEventLoop.java:206)
    at com.aerospike.client.async.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:165)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at com.aerospike.client.async.NioConnection.read(NioConnection.java:112)
    at com.aerospike.client.async.NioCommand.read(NioCommand.java:240)
    at com.aerospike.client.async.NioEventLoop.processKey(NioEventLoop.java:254)
    ... 2 more
```

Even if I am following the steps mentioned in aerospike website for async client
    http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/java/usage/async

On debugging deep I found it is from class :com.aerospike.client.async.NioConnection

method :

```
    public boolean read(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) throws IOException {
        while (byteBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
            int len = socketChannel.read(byteBuffer);

            if (len == 0) {         
                // Got would-block.
                return false;
            }

            if (len < 0) {
                // Server has shutdown socket.
                throw new EOFException();
            }
        }`
        return true;
    }
```

But not getting any configuration to fix it.

Comment: Also listed on: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/eofexception-with-async-client/4506

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the right place to report what seems like a bug. This is an open source repo, so open a new issue: https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/issues

Comment: At what point does this happen? How long is the application running? If you set [`proto-fd-max`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#proto-fd-max) higher does it take longer for the issue to surface?

Comment: Are you closing the channel when you get this exception?